# JavaScript template that allows function evaluating

Tags: javascript, datatemplate, eval

I'm searching for a JavaScript template that allows function evaluating.

Consider the following JSON:

```
{"Name":"Joao", "BirthDate":"1985"}
```

I would like to able to do something like

```
<span>
    {{Name}} age is getAge({{BirthDate}})
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [jQuery Template](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

Here's a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/dcardoso/ZcraD/) of function evaluating.

Comment: Here's a [write up](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx) and more examples.

Answer (score 1):

[John Resig produced a small templating engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) that does something similar to this (albeit with slightly different syntax), I've used it a couple of times with great success. It's got a very small footprint and can be easily pasted into your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Nano](https://github.com/trix/nano) which is a jQuery plugin for just this!

I know it's jQuery, but it relies on the JSON methods.

Answer (score 0):

Mustache - https://github.com/janl/mustache.js.

It's lightning fast, has the exact syntax you're looking for and can evaluate functions in the manner you need. There are a lot of other powerful additions. Very good templating framework